# Sending custom notifications in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I'm trying to develop a new Bamboo Notification Plugin.

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/building-a-notification-plugin/) - if I want to create a Custom Notification, in which I want to add a log file as attachment to my email, for example, I need to implement the following interface ExtendedNotification.

```
public class MyNotification extends AbstractNotification implements ExtendedNotification {
    ...
}
```

This interface *ExtendedNotification* has the following method that needs to be implemented:

```
@NotNull
@Override
public Email updateEmail (@NotNull Email email) {
   return null;
}
```

The problem is when building the *Email* itself - getting the build version from the context in this method doesn't work ( to try to attach the correct log file).
For example, if I have the following log file - \BAMBOO\tools\logs\${bamboo.planKey}\health_${bamboo.buildNumber}.txt). 
Below is the code of the full method.

```
@NotNull
@Override
public Email updateEmail (@NotNull Email email) {
   try {

      //VariableContext variables = taskContext.getBuildContext ().getVariableContext ();

      // E:\Atlassian\BAMBOO\tools\logs\${bamboo.planKey}\health_${bamboo.buildNumber}.txt
      File logFile = new File ("E:\\Atlassian\\BAMBOO\\tools\\logs\\" + taskContext.getBuildContext().getPlanKey () + "\\health_" + taskContext.getBuildContext().getBuildNumber() + ".txt");

      //Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
      Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart ();

      // creates body part for the message
      MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart ();
      messageBodyPart.setContent (getHtmlEmailContent (), "text/html");

      // creates body part for the attachment
      MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart ();

      // code to add attachment...will be revealed later
      attachPart.attachFile (logFile);

      // adds parts to the multipart
      multipart.addBodyPart (messageBodyPart);
      multipart.addBodyPart (attachPart);

      // sets the multipart as message's content
      email.setMultipart (multipart);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error ("There was a problem composing the email", e);
      return null;
   }
   return email;
}
```

My problem is getting the key plan variable in Bamboo, in Java. In my code above I tried getting it by using:

```
taskContext.getBuildContext ().getVariableContext ();
```

as described here [StackOverflow question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-access-build-variables-from-a-bamboo-task/qaq-p/572570), but this doesn't work.

I saw an example of building a Custom Notification here - [enter link description here](https://github.com/carolynvs/bamboo-deployment-notifications), but the code is quite old and it doesn't use any attachments.

Any idea on how to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the way to make it work.

Those variable I want to get, the *planKey* and the *buildNumber* are coming from the following :

```
public class MyNotification extends AbstractCompletedNotification implements ExtendedNotification {
    private ResultsSummary resultsSummary;
    private ImmutablePlan plan;
    ...

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Email updateEmail (@NotNull Email email) {
        try {

            File logFile = new File ("E:\\Atlassian\\BAMBOO\\tools\\logs\\" + 
                plan.getPlanKey () + 
                "\\health_" + 
                resultsSummary.getBuildNumber() + 
                ".txt");
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And the *plan* and the *resultSummary* are set in the **MyNotificationEventListener** when I create my custom notification - **MyNotification** :

```
public class MyNotificationEventListener {
    ...
    @EventListener
    @HibernateEventListenerAspect
    public void handleEvent (@NotNull Object event) {
        if (event instanceof ChainCompletedEvent) { // for example
            ... 
            MyNotification myNotification = (MyNotification) BambooNotificationUtils.createNotification (MyNotification.class);
            ...
            myNotification.setResultsSummary (this.resultsSummaryManager.getResultsSummary (chainCompletedEvent.getPlanResultKey ()));
            ImmutablePlan immutablePlan = this.planManager.getPlanByKey (chainCompletedEvent.getPlanKey ());
            myNotification.setPlan (immutablePlan);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```